# проблема с tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Проблема состоит в том что у меня есть два проекта один на JavaEE, второй на SpringMVC, на tomcat, изначально для дву проектов я использовал один и тот же tomcat, но получилось так что я всегда попадаю на одну и ту же страницу, если точнее то из первого проекта я попадаю на главную страницу второго проекта. Я решил скачать еще раз tomcat чтобы для разных проектов был разный сервер и по итогу все равно происходит тоже самое, что делать?)

Проблема состоит в том что у меня есть два проекта на tomcat, изначально для дву проектов я использовал один и тот же tomcat, но получилось так что я всегда попадаю на одну и ту же страницу, если точнее то из первого проекта я попадаю на главную страницу второго проекта. Я решил скачать еще раз tomcat чтобы для разных проектов был разный сервер и по итогу все равно происходит тоже самое, что делать?